# Run Broadcast at specific time

Tags: android, broadcast

```
    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    // cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, value);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, broadcastthepairs.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (cal.getTimeInMillis() + 3000),
            pintent);
```

The mainfest

```
<receiver android:name="cryptsy.pricelist.broadcastthepairs" >

    </receiver>
```

Alright so i want to start a broadcast that in turn starts a service at 15: something time.
I have searched this code from web  and all are similar to this one but i cannot get them working can you tell me what i am doin wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating wrong `PendingIntent`. You should use `getBroadcast()` instead of `getService()`.

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
```